# Enabling Microsoft Update in Windows 11 via Registry

Tags: windows-registry, windows-update, windows-11

How do I enable the optional "*Receive Updates for other Microsoft Products*" service via registry in Windows 11? I have tried the below "**AllowMUUpdateService**" registry key, among others, to no avail:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v AllowMUUpdateService /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v AutoInstallMinorUpdates /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v NoAutoUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v ScheduledInstallDay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\AU /v ScheduledInstallTime /t REG_DWORD /d 12 /f
```

Here is a screenshot of all the registry keys added:

[Auto Update Registry Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb8V4.png)

Even after these registry values are added, the optional Microsoft Update is still turned OFF:

[Windows Update Option: Receive Updates for other Microsoft Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFVO9.png)

Related, I noticed that the PowerShell 7.2 setup will properly toggle the Microsoft Update service during installation. What is this setup file doing in the registry that the above registry key/values I am attempting are not accomplishing?

[PowerShell 7 Setup Option: Use Microsoft Update when I check for updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itOiK.png)

Comment: Is it RegisteredWithAU under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Services\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D`

Comment: @HelpingHand Yes, the RegisteredWithAU (REG_DWORD) is set to the value of "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trials and tribulations, I've discovered a Microsoft article that explains the opt-in to the Microsoft Update service can no longer be performed by registry edits alone. The steps to enable this optional service **require** that you explicitly register the machine using the Windows Update Agent (WUA) via a simple VBScript (`.vbs`) file:

### RegisterMicrosoftUpdate.vbs

```
Set ServiceManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager")
ServiceManager.ClientApplicationID = "My App"

'Add the Microsoft Update Service, GUID
Set NewUpdateService = ServiceManager.AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")
```

Additionally—if you are using batch scripts—you can run this VBScript file by adding the following line:

```
start cscript "EnableMicrosoftUpdate.vbs"
```

---

***NOTE:*** Remember to run your `.vbs` or `.bat` file as Administrator or else the Microsoft Update service registration will fail.

*via Microsoft article:* [Opt-In to Microsoft Update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/opt-in-to-microsoft-update)

Comment: What are the consequences of making the ID "My App"? Will I see a scheduled task or something else named this? Is there any harm in making it descriptive?

Comment: Also, are there consequences to running this multiple times? Will it keep creating services or will it overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

The same script as PowerShell:

```
$ServiceManager = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager
$ServiceManager.ClientApplicationID = "My App"
$NewUpdateService = $ServiceManager.AddService2("7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d",7,"")
```