# Opt in Microsoft Automatic Updates using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am setting up a VM running Windows Server 2022. I'm trying to subscribe to Automatic Updates according to this document I found on MS website.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/opt-in-to-microsoft-update

I also found this answer here.
[Enabling Microsoft Update in Windows 11 via Registry](https://superuser.com/questions/1712804/enabling-microsoft-update-in-windows-11-via-registry)

However, when tried, I don't even see that ID in the newly created `Service Manager`.

```
$wu = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager -Strict

$wu.AddService2('7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d', 7, '')
```

I even introduced a `Start-Sleep` afterwards but at no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Automatic Updates"? Your second link is for enabling the optional "Receive Updates for other Microsoft Products".